# SMTP Error: Could not authenticate using PHPMailer and Gmail account

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to send an email using PHPMailer and from my gmail account. But it shows

> SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password
> not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8
> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials
> 5-20020aca0605000000b0037d8d231f8csm951314oig.51 - gsmtp SMTP Error:
> Could not authenticate.

Unfortunately, the option to use "less secure apps" has been turned off by Google, so that option is not available to me. What are some other options I can try to resolve this issue?

Here is my current script:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'lsurahman157@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'mypasswodis!';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('lsurahman157@gmail.com', 'Full Name');
    $mail->addAddress('aonik1@lsu.edu', 'Abdur Rahman Onik');     // Add a recipient

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Subject Text';
    $mail->Body    = '<i>Mail body in HTML</i>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the plain text version of the email content';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: What did you find lacking in [the docs on this subject](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps)?

Answer (score -1):

If you activate MFA for your account, you are able to define App-Passwords. You can use the passwords for SMTP an IMAP authentication.

Comment: Do you mean to activate 2-factor authentication and then use the app-password in password field?

Comment: Yes. If 2-factor authentication is enabled, you can also define different App-Passwords just below the 2-factor authentication settings. These passwords can be used for SMTP and IMAP